# How do I get os family in maven pom file?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to generate a JAR including OS name and need a property in POM file that would contain value like "windows" or "macos"?

Is there such property available?

Comment: Can you explain why you need the OS name for a jar?

Comment: I just want to include it in the jar's name

Comment: I'm asking why? If it is just an idea or wish then it would be helpful to know why? What purpose for?

Comment: As I build a JAR on different platforms (for the same project) I would like the JAR name to include the OS name on which it is currently built.

Comment: First why building the same jar on different platform because a jar is platform independent... So why this? And in particular for the same project?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [reference](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html). You need `os.name`.

Comment: Thanks but this gives me "Windows 10" and I would like something like "windows"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [os-maven-plugin](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin) (also works as an extension). Maven does not provide such functionality by default, as java *should* be OS and arch agnostic.

The [generated properties](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin#generated-properties) include `os.detected.name`, which should serve your needs.